# Extract Data In Broadcast Receiver Class

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an app.I am sending my registration id getting from Google from broadcast receiver class to Main Activity class by using this code.

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.example.sampletestproject.REGISTER_DEVICE"). putExtra("GCM_REG_ID",registrationId));
```

now I want to receive this registration id in Main Activity class. I am trying to do this by creating a new broadcast receiver class but not getting value.
 The code for Main Activity is.

```
Button bt1,bt2;

BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.sampletestproject.REGISTER_DEVICE"));

    bt1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            //Log.d("msg", "Button clicked");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent registrationIntent=new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
        //  Log.d("msg", "Intent created");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Intent created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(v.getContext(),0,new Intent(),0));
            registrationIntent.putExtra("senderid","908614649566");
            startService(registrationIntent);
            //Log.d("msg", "Intent Registered");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Intent Register", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    bt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent unregintent=new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
            unregintent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(v.getContext(),0, new Intent(), 0));
            startService(unregintent);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Intent unregister", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

     mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            //post registration id to server
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "within new broadcast receiver in mainactivity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent it=getIntent();
            it.getExtras().get("GCM_REG_ID");

        }
    };

}
```

Comment: first initialize the `mReceiver`, then register it...

Comment: interface callback will be more usefull in my opinion

Comment: BroadcastReceiver registor in manifestfile ?

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this.

Button bt1,bt2;

BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
bt1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
bt2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        //Log.d("msg", "Button clicked");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent registrationIntent=new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    //  Log.d("msg", "Intent created");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Intent created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(v.getContext(),0,new Intent(),0));
        registrationIntent.putExtra("senderid","908614649566");
        startService(registrationIntent);
        //Log.d("msg", "Intent Registered");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Intent Register", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
bt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent unregintent=new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
        unregintent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(v.getContext(),0, new Intent(), 0));
        startService(unregintent);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Intent unregister", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});

 mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //post registration id to server
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "within new broadcast receiver in mainactivity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent it=getIntent();
        it.getExtras().get("GCM_REG_ID");

    }
};registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.sampletestproject.REGISTER_DEVICE"));
```

}

Comment: Force close . please give another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since The Receiver is created in Activity, so receiver will be active only if activity is up.
Better Idea is created receiver separately, and register in Android Manifest 
refer [this example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Comment: but i want my result in mainactivity.so creating an another receiver separately is not a good option.